# Tearing / dropped frames in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

The following code draws a small white disc orbiting the center of the screen. There is noticeable tearing on my machine (macOS Monterey) and 6 or 7 frames are dropped on average on each revolution. Is there any way to avoid that? I've tried adding flags such as `vsync`, `fullscreen`, `scaled` etc, nothing works. The `opengl` flag doesn't seem to work on macos.

```py
import pygame
import sys
import math

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1920,1080))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:

    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    t = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    screen.fill('Black')
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, 'White', (
        960 + 300 * math.cos(t / 800),
        540 + 300 * math.sin(t / 800)),
        20)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

To be clear: IMHO the frames are not dropping because of heavy or background CPU usage. A modified version of this code runs approximately 1000 such circles all over the screen pretty smoothly, with only the regular hiccup here and there (same as above). I only start to get real slowdowns when I go over 5000 circles.

Comment: You could first draw the circle on a surface before the loop and then blit that surface every time again.

Comment: Firstly I can say that using `vsync=True` seemingly helped a bit but I guess not for you. I could suggest you `round` the position, that may help a bit, but otherwise and referencing [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/3blsr3/jittering_movement/) reddit thread, you can't really do anything much apparently about it, but as also stated there, then in a game or in general when there would be more moving stuff, the smearing may not be as noticeable because you'd be focusing on other things on the screen too. But I really like the way you asked the question and that it had a neat [mre]!

Comment: Another important bit is that `vsync` only works with displays that have `pygame.SCALED` or `pygame.OPENGL` flags set so you may want to try with those, however the behaviour of `vsync` is considered experimental and even with those flags it's not guaranteed to use it, however, without those flags it's certain to not be used. (https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode)

Comment: You are drawing 2 million pixels for every frame.  You might consider, instead of filling the screen, just drawing over the previous circle with the background color.  So, kill the `screen.fill`, and do `draw.circle( ... 'White' )`, then `display.update`, then `draw.circle( ... 'Black' )`.  That's noticably smoother for me.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly - check that there is not some CPU-heavy task running on your machine.  For the moment I would just write your program, and then worry about if/when it's dropping frames later.  If it's still an issue at completion, *then* optimise it.

One way to speed this up is to pass the rectangle for changed screen area to the `pygame.display.update( dirty_rectangle )` function.   That way only the part of the screen that has been "dirtied" by changes will be updated.  This means that *typically* a smaller part of the screen will be re-drawn.

I also modified the code to draw the circle to an off-screen surface, and just `blit()` that image to the screen, rather than re-calculate the circle each loop.  That makes it easy to work out the corners of the changed area too.

For your example, it's possible to calculate this rectangle based on the position of the circle, and where it has been previously.  So before repositioning the circle to the new co-ordinate, we make a copy of `circle_rect` into `previous_rect`.   The new position is calculated, the drawing position updated.  The maximum extent of the update is then the minimum top-left corner of both rectangles, down to the maximum of the bottom-right corners.  The min & max is used to populate the update rectangle.

```
import pygame
import sys
import math

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1920,1080))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Create a sprite for the circle
CIRCLE_RAD=20
circle = pygame.Surface( (CIRCLE_RAD*2, CIRCLE_RAD*2), pygame.SRCALPHA, 32 )
circle.fill( (0,0,0) )
pygame.draw.circle( circle, (255,255,255), (CIRCLE_RAD,CIRCLE_RAD), CIRCLE_RAD )
circle_rect = circle.get_rect()
update_rect = circle_rect.copy()

while True:

    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    previous_rect = circle_rect.copy()
    t = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    t800 = t/800
    circle_rect.center = ( 960 + 300 * math.cos(t800), 540 + 300 * math.sin(t800) )

    # work out the size of the update
    min_x = min( previous_rect.x, circle_rect.x )
    min_y = min( previous_rect.y, circle_rect.y )
    max_x = max( previous_rect.x + previous_rect.width, circle_rect.x + circle_rect.width )
    max_y = max( previous_rect.y + previous_rect.height, circle_rect.y + circle_rect.height )
    update_rect.update( min( previous_rect.x, circle_rect.x ),
                        min( previous_rect.y, circle_rect.y ),
                        max_x-min_x,
                        max_y-min_y )


    screen.fill('Black')
    screen.blit( circle, circle_rect )
    pygame.display.update( update_rect )

    ms_since_previous = clock.tick(60)
    if ( ms_since_previous > 17 ):      # 60FPS is about 17ms between frames
        print( "Slow update: %d milliseconds" % ( ms_since_previous ) )
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. On my machine, the result is almost identical to the original example (and the "slow update" message appears around 5-6 times per second, corresponding to the visible hiccups). Not related to the CPU I believe, I've added some details to the original question.

Comment: Btw, I don't think that's an accurate way to tell slow updates apart, that code can easily run at much much more than 60 FPS with no "hiccups", those slow frames are likely tiny imprecisions in the sleeping mechanism that is used by `pygame.time.Clock.tick` likely to reduce CPU load that precision sleeping would require.

Comment: FWIW I can't see any difference in the result when using `Clock.tick` with any values I've tested (120, 60, 30, 25), or when commenting out `Clock.tick` completely for that matter. The visible tearing and frame dropping is identical as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Matiiss - I agree completely, and what you say is true.  Dragging the window around, for example, causes lots of "untimely" updates.   But it is "good enough" for a rough idea of timing issues.